# Mapserver mapinfo styling

Tags: gis, mapserver, mapinfo

Is it possible to use mapinfo embedded graphic style for features with mapserver?
I don't want to describe again width and color of lines, polygones and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The styling should be picked up automatically:

http://mapserver.org/input/vector/mapinfo.html

> MapInfo files already contain styling
>   information. This styling information
>   can be used optionally by specifying
>   the STYLEITEM “AUTO” parameter in the
>   LAYER object of the map file.
>
> Note
>
> If you use STYLEITEM “AUTO” you must
>   have an empty class in the layer.

Example:

```
LAYER
NAME Elevation_Poly_5
TYPE POLYGON
STATUS DEFAULT
CONNECTIONTYPE OGR
CONNECTION "./hypso/elev5_poly.TAB"
STYLEITEM "AUTO"
CLASS
        NAME "Elevation Poly 5"
END
END # Layer
```